# Which Linux distro for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, web-applications

What is the best linux distro for deploying ruby on rails web apps on a production server.

The web app will use advanced cache features, graph creations and lots of other cool features.

Please advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82396/whats-the-best-linux-distribution-for-ruby-on-rails-development-and-hosting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like Ubuntu Server mostly cause it's well supported and readily available on almost all cloud services.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 14, No Doubt... Actually there's a tutorial on how to setup a Complete RoR Development Enviroment in the Blog where I write... The post is in Spanish but I believe you'll understand terminal commands quite good:

> http://xenodesystems.blogspot.com/2011/01/instalar-ruby-on-rails-en-linux-con.html

Also there's a Gadget on the Blog to translate posts into different Languages...

Good Luck!

Comment: I use Fedora myself, but I agree with Blender. While great for development, it simply isn't designed to be the best option for a production server.

Comment: I have a different opinion... That's just a myth, I use Fedora on all my production machines/servers and it work just fine :) Never had a problem and I've been using it since Fedora 11 Leonidas.

Comment: To tell you the truth, there is no answer to the OP's question. All Linux distros are essentially the same, with minor differences like package managers and pre-installed software. I could use any (`*NIX`) OS for a server, including Fedora, so there's no real reason to not use it (or any other distro for that matter). I just use Arch because my server is a refurbished dinosaur with *serious* RAM and disk-space limitations, and Arch runs in under 40MB of RAM for me, which leaves more than enough horsepower to run Python and Lighttpd.

Answer (score 1):

Taking account that Rails relies substantially in console commands, any Unix based distribution will be good. My advice: use whatever you feel comfortable with. If that's not the case and you want to learn a suitable distro for Rails, I would recommend Fedora as Jmlevick suggested.
For Rails,it usually offers latest Ruby version directly in the distribution. Also the whole Rails is packaged as RPMs, making it easier to instal. You just need to download the RPM version of the gem with pre-compiled extension and you're done.

If you want to see the docs about [Ruby](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/ruby/ruby-installation.html) or [Rails](https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tech/languages/ruby/ror-installation.html) directly from Fedora check out the links.

Also to take into account, Fedora is a friendly user distro, easy to install and it has a huge community, so in case of a problem, just do some research. In case that you have Mac, that would be also fine.